# Can't figure out what this onClick handler with 2 functions and an || ( OR ) operator does

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I saw this React onClick handler:

```
onClick={backToPreviousPage || (() => window.history.back())}
```

And I can't exactly figure out the logic of the || operator inside this click handler and what does it accomplish. Which function would actually execute on the click if both are defined. Does it tries to execute `backToPreviousPage` first, and then `window.history.back()` if backToPreviousPage is not defined?

Comment: See the linked questions for details. JavaScript's `||` is (as I say in [this post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html)) curiously powerful. Instead of resulting in `true` or `false`, it results in the value of one of its operands. When evaluating `a || b`, `a` is evaluated and if the result is *truthy*, that value is used as the result of the `||`. If the result of evaluating `a` is *falsy*, `b` is evaluated and that result is used as the result of the `||`. So in the code you've shown, if `backToPreviousPage` has a truthy value, that's...

Comment: ...used; otherwise, `(() => window.history.back())` is evaluated (creating a function) and used. *"Does it tries to execute `backToPreviousPage` first"* No, because there are no `()` after `backToPreviousPage`. It uses the function object, it doesn't **call** the function.

Comment: *"falsy"* = is considered `false` in conditions. The falsy values are `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course `false` (also, bizarrely, `document.all` on browsers). All other values are *truthy*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you, I was relatively confused because I've never used the OR operator in such a way.

Comment: My pleasure! I should have noted that in modern code you'd probably see `??` in that situation instead (the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)) (`backtoPreviousPage` is probably `null` or `undefined` when it's falsy). `||` was often used for this before `??` was added (fairly recently).